# Using case inside where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I´m trying to create a procedure that has a parameter called m_reaplicacao. This parameter receives the values 'S' for Yes, 'N' for No and 'T' for all records. 
When the parameter is Yes, I should return the records with value equals to 9. 
When the parameter is No, I should return the records different of 9. And finally, when the the value is All, I should return all records from the table.
With the code bellow, Oracle says: 
Compilation errors for PROCEDURE MYDB.CONTAS_A_PAGAR_SPS
Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
Line: 84
Text: ta.id_1a_cbr = 9;

```
    select * from proposta ta
    where 
          ta.estado = 'RJ'
          and case
               when m_reaplicacao = 'S' then
                    ta.id_1a_cbr = 9;
               when m_reaplicacao = 'N' then
                    ta.id_1a_cbr <> 9
               else null
          end case;
```

I saw a lot of posts, but I did not solve this one.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Use `END` not `END CASE`. And you may need to move `m_reaplicacao =` outside the case statment.

Comment: Whoops, that's supposed to be `ta.id_1a_cbr` outside the case statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use a `CASE` statement in a `WHERE` clause when you really want a simple combination of boolean evaluations.

```
WHERE ta.estado = 'RJ'
  AND (    m_reaplicacao = 'T'
       OR (m_reaplicacao = 'S' AND ta.id_1a_cbr = 9)
       OR (m_reaplicacao = 'N' AND ta.id_1a_cbr <> 9)
      )
```

If for some reason you really do want to use a `CASE` statement, you'd need the `CASE` to return a value that you check in the `WHERE` clause.  For example

```
WHERE ta.estado = 'RJ'
  AND (CASE WHEN m_reaplicacao = 'S' AND ta.id_1a_cbr = 9 
            THEN 1
            WHEN m_reaplicacao = 'N' AND ta.id_1a_cbr <> 9 
            THEN 1
            WHEN m_reaplicacao = 'T'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END) = 1
```

This is not generally the clearest way to express this sort of condition, however.

Comment: Why do compare 1 to the case statement?

Comment: @BabyboBNukes - You have to compare the `case` statement to something if you use that approach (like I said, I wouldn't suggest using the `case` in the first place).  1 is just an easy value to return and compare against.  You could return -1 or 17 or 'a' and compare to that same value if you chose.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return expressions in `CASE` statements, easiest to add additional `WHERE` criteria sets:

```
select * 
from proposta ta
where ta.estado = 'RJ'
  and (
         (m_reaplicacao = 'S' AND ta.id_1a_cbr = 9)
      OR (m_reaplicacao = 'N' AND ta.id_1a_cbr <> 9)
       )
```

Not sure what you want to happen in the `NULL` situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE in select statements, like this:

```
with d as (
  select 'A' as val from dual
  union
  select 'B' as val from dual
  union
  select 'C' as val from dual
)
select *
from d
where 
    case 
        when val = 'A' then 1
        when val = 'B' then 1
        when val = 'Z' then 1
    end = 1;
```

Here we're looking for rows where val in ('A','B','Z').  In this example, its another way of writing:

```
select ... where val in ('A','B','Z');
```