# Case in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the wrong with this code?

```
select emp_id, emp_name 
from emp 
where case  when :emp.designation_id = '008' then designation_id = '003'
```

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249323/using-case-inside-where-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` is an expression that returns a value.  And a `case` expression ends with `end`.  And a `case` expression returns a valid type.

Perhaps you intend:

```
select emp_id, emp_name 
from emp
where designation_id = (case when :emp.designation_id = '008' then designation_id = '003' end);
```

A simpler way to express *this* logic without `case` is:

```
where :emp.designation_id = '008' and designation_id = '003'
```

But you probably really intend:

```
where (:emp.designation_id = '008' and designation_id = '003') or
      (:emp.designation_id <> '008' and designation_id = :emp.designation_id)
```